# Confused on how a value gets added with the DEFAULT constraint

Tags: sql-server, database-design, constraint, default-value

A recent definition I've read about Default Constraints:

*DEFAULT is specified for a column to assign a column a specific value if no value is specified when a row is added.*

I believe I've seen code written without the DEFAULT constraint specified and a NULL value was assigned to the field.

If I add a column to a table, do I have specify the DEFAULT keyword for the default value to be assigned?  Or will NULL be assigned since I didn't delineate DEFAULT?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Apologies, excuse my ignorance, I was thinking this was a standard among all modern DBMS'.  The example I saw related to MS SQL Server.

Comment: It it more or less standard, but still different DBMS behave differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your column definition does not have default constraint and it is nullable, the nullable field will have `null` mark, when you add a row even when you specify `DEFAULT` keyword for your insert value. For example for the following table definition

```
 CREATE TABLE Test(
    ColA  [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    COLB [nvarchar](50) NULL)
```

The first three insert statements will insert NULL mark for ColB. Only the last one will have ColB value assigned.

```
 insert into Test(ColA, ColB) values ('a', DEFAULT);
 insert into Test(ColA, ColB) values ('b', NULL);
 insert into Test(ColA) values ('c');
 insert into Test(ColA, ColB) values ('d', 'e');
```

Whereas for the following table definition with `DEFAULT` constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
    ColA  [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    COLB [nvarchar](50) NULL DEFAULT 'x')
```

Only the second statement below will insert NULL mark for ColB. The first and the third statements will assign 'x' as the DEFAULT value.

```
 insert into Test(ColA, ColB) values ('a', DEFAULT);
 insert into Test(ColA, ColB) values ('b', NULL);
 insert into Test(ColA) values ('c');
 insert into Test(ColA, ColB) values ('d', 'e');
```